# Force 'general' string formatting in Python for low exponents

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, string-formatting, number-formatting

[General formatting](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) in Python rounds the number to `p` significant digits and prints as a float (`%f`) if the exponent `exp` is between `-4 <= exp < p`, otherwise it prints in scientific exponent notation (`%e`). For example:

```
> '{0:0.8G}'.format(10000000)
'10000000'
> '{0:0.8G}'.format(0.000001)
'1E-06'
```

Why does this condition only allow you to specify the upper exponent limit precision, whereas the lower exponent limit is fixed at -4? Is there any way of forcing string formatting to print the full number for low exponents?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way of forcing string formatting to print the full number
>   for low exponents?

There's no way to force `G` to always format using fixed-point notation, but you can use `f` with custom precision combined with `.rstrip()`:

```
>>> '{:.10f}'.format(0.0000000001)
'0.0000000001'
>>> '{:.10f}'.format(0.00001).rstrip('0')  # remove trailing zeros
'0.00001'
>>> '{:.10f}'.format(1000).rstrip('0').rstrip('.')  # remove trailing zeros and '.'
'1000'
```

Comment: unfortunately this does not take account of the significant digits as in general mode, so that '{:.10f}'.format(0.00001) gives '0.0000100000'

Comment: You can use `.rstrip()` in addition to `.format()` (see the update).

Comment: Answers the second question (can also be used with [FuncFormatter](https://matplotlib.org/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter) in matplotlib if required) but not the first. Is -4 just an arbitrary choice for the lower exponent precision limit?